# Yup validation message not appearing in .test()

Tags: formik, yup, react-forms

apologize in advance cause I am fairly new to yup. I am using the .test() function to run some code and display a message if false. It seems to do the right job in validating and preventing form submission, however the error message is not displayed.

This following is what I have:

```
owners: yup
    .array()
    .of(ownerSchema)
    .required('Must select an owner')
    .when('ownership_type', {
      is: (value: string) => value === 'JOINT_TENANTS_IN_COMMON' || value === 'JOINT_TENANTS_WITH_SURVIVORSHIP',
      then: yup.array().min(2, 'Must selected more than one owner')
    })
    .test('pct-sum', 'Ownership should be equal to 100%', (owners) => {
      if (owners && owners.length === 0) return false
      const sum = _.sumBy(owners, 'pct_owned')
      return sum === 100
    })
    .test('duplicates', 'Duplicate owners are not allowed', (owners) => {
      const ownerList: string[] = []
      owners?.forEach(owner =>
        ownerList.push(owner.participant || '')
      )
      return ownerList.length === new Set(ownerList).size
    }),
```

I am expecting both `Ownership should be equal to 100%` and `Duplicate owners are not allowed` to be shown to user, however neither are shown. Both seem to prevent form submission though